# Show unbuilt changes in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am looking for a plugin for VS 2012 that would show me which lines of code have been modified or created since the last build. Anyone know of something for this?

Comment: Are you talking about lines of code that have been *modified / created* since the last build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [Visual Studio SVN](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/DBD60715-FE57-44B5-ABEA-F18618068C1E) plugin to view changes visually within Visual Studio.

EDIT: as mentioned in my comment below, the next closest thing to what you seek is [change tracking](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/enhanced-track-change-features-in-visual/229300243). As you bring up in your comment it will only work for your purposes if the only time you save is when you build. I tend to save as often as possible though.

And yes, the default behavior of VS is to automatically save when you build.

Comment: This would show me changes made compared to source. I don't commit every time I build.

Comment: Right, well then, unfortunately I'm unaware of anything that can be used to track per-build changes. The next closest thing would be [change tracking](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/enhanced-track-change-features-in-visual/229300243).

Comment: This will work as long as you only save when you build. If you edit your answer to convey this, I will flag it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Ebalders - I'm pretty sure VS automatically saves when you build.  At the very least there's an option to do so, and it seems to be on by default.